# How to set current data (not newData)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

The Firebase Realtime Database Rules simulator is a very powerful way to test your rules.  However, it is not clear that you can simulate current data values. It seems that you can only test `newData` values.

That is, I can't seem to simulate rules that contain, for example (the actual rule here isn't important, just that it contains references to `data`, not just `newData`):

```
".write": data.child('child1').val() > newData.child('child2').val()
```

The simulator seems to allow the setting of `newData`, but not `data`. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current data is always read from your existing Firebase Database. There is no way to specify a different value for `data` in the simulator.